# How android update ui

Tags: android

Android recommend update ui in the ui thread,but i found that i can update the ui in the non-ui thread directly like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText("SecondThread");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}
That's run correctly,but if i sleep the thread 1000ms:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                **Thread.sleep(1000);**
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textView.setText("SecondThread");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}
I get the error"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views",i try to change the sleep value much times,i found when i set the value 135 or less,it can run correctly：
Thread.sleep(135);

Thread.sleep(134);

Thread.sleep(...);
That's very interesting!But why it happen?I can't find any way to make sense of that,is anyone can help me?thanks!

Comment: You should not modify the UI from a background Thread at all. Even though it "works" with some values of sleep(), it is not the correct thing to do, and will cause problems.

Comment: Probably because you get the update in in between frames. Longer than that you run into sync issues. But why for the love of Baal would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: You can use runOnUiThread method or Handler.post

Comment: Thanks your answer,but i‘m sorry about that i do not know if I have made my question clear,i know how to update views in non-ui thread,i just can't understand why android can't report an error like "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" when i use the first way above,i update my textview in a non-ui thread directly and i get the result correctly when i run my application,the content text "SecondThread" display on screen and i don't get any error......it makes me very puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to touch views from background thread you should consider using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method, which accepts runnable as argument in which you can update views

EDIT: Also I would recommed you to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to achieve your goals, it has two callbacks [onPreExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) and [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29), whiche are invoked on the UI thread

Comment: Thanks your answer,but i‘m sorry about that i do not know if I have made my question clear,i know how to update views in non-ui thread,i just can't understand why android can't report an error like "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" when i use the first way above,i update my textview in a non-ui thread directly and i get the result correctly when i run my application,the content text "SecondThread" display on screen and i don't get any error......it makes me very puzzling.

Comment: I think in this case it has more to do with how do you launch a new thread, because it seems like in your case you still can touch views from the second thread, this makes a topic for a serious research:)

Answer (score 0):

so will always work

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                **Thread.sleep(1000);**
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runable(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
               textView.setText("SecondThread");
            });

        }
    }).start();
```

There is another way to use the `Handler()`